Why is the $K^{0}_{S}$ meson decay mostly into two pions and not semileptonic?
I understand why the $K^{0}_{S}$ (short-lived) decays into two pions, while the $K^{0}_{L}$ (long) also can decay into two pions, due to CP conservation.  It's also clear to me why the latter process is more rare (because the phase space is smaller).
However, I'm puzzled by why the semileptonic decays ($K^{0}_{S}\rightarrow \pi+l+\nu$) are so much rarer than the $K^{0}_{S}\rightarrow 2\pi$ decay, so much that they are comparable to the $K^{0}_{L}\rightarrow 3\pi$ decay. The diagrams are virtually identical ($s \rightarrow u+W$) with the $W$ decaying into $l \nu$ in one case and $u+d$ in the other. Given this similarity, I would expect at most a factor of three difference in their rates, not the order of 1000 difference observed in $K^{0}_{S}$ decays [Br$(K^{0}_{S}\rightarrow \pi+l+\nu)$ = 0.03%]. What am I missing? It's not CP conservation since $\pi+l+\nu$ is not a CP eigenstate, and it's not phase space as $m(\pi+e+\nu) \ll m(2\pi)$. I'm a trained particle physicist, and I’m embarrassed that I neither know nor can find an answer to this question.

Why the 2pi decay swamps everything? The diagram is the same as for the semileptonic channel, with the only thing different is the W decay. The decya into 3 pi is completely different.

I could give you a semi-quantitative answer, but the short answer is that it is not an issue of the quark Feynman diagrams underlying the weak transition, but how these hadronize into the effective weak hamiltonian by dint of QCD, often obscurely.
All such strangeness-violating decay widths go like the square of the Fermi constant (there is a $1/M_W^2$ in all diagrams, squared to 1/$M^4$), so, on dimensional grounds,  the width must go as the fifth power of characteristic momenta, elaborate phase-space factors, modified by strong hadronization dressings...
Chapter IX of the go-to text, viz , attributes the 2+ orders of magnitude width enhancement of the $_$ vs $_$
to phase space of 2-body vs 3-body decays, consistent with the above exponent of 5, which I think I recall as the canonical explanation from graduate school, a lifetime ago.

So the 2-body decay swamps the rate.

Edit: A tip of the hat to @atlas-insider who comment-reminded me why the ratio of the 2π to the semileptonic decays widths are so dramatically different in $^+$ versus $^0_S$, effectively the relative BRs of 2π vs 3π decays of the $K^+$: the somewhat exceptional $~~~~^0_S$ to 2π is enhanced by the effective  Δ=1/2 rule of the weak hamiltonian, a (just-so but real) QCD hadronization effect; while $K^+$ to 2π can only go through the suppressed Δ=3/2 term, and so does not swamp that rate. (Donoghue et al, above, discuss the rule in Ch VIII-4.)

for your side question: the $\pi\pi$ final state can have total isospin 0 (only for $K^0$) or 2 (both), while $I=1$ is ruled out (cf 441957 and 166331). The observed predominance of the $I=0$ contribution to the kaon decay amplitude is the so-called $\Delta I=1/2$ rule; arXiv:2307.15737 (section 4) atttributes it to "QCD dynamics".

Thanks, you got it! Δ=3/2 processes are suppressed by (obscure but very real) strong dynamics. You made me slap my forehead!
